# What we can say about the monotonocity of the function $f$ near zero

Tags: real-analysis, monotone-functions, analytic-functions

Let us consider a **real analytic function** $f$. Let us consider the Taylor expansion for $f$ at $x=0$:
$$f(x)=b+ax+O(x²)$$

where $b=f(0)$ and $a=f′(0)$

Assuming that $a>0$ so the Taylor expansion for $f$ at $x=0$ is increasing locally near zero.

My **question** is:

What we can say about the **monotonocity** of the function $f$ near zero, i.e., Is the function $f$ increasing just like its approximation.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Are you asking if increasing functions are monotone?

Comment: I'm a little confused. You already seem to know that $f$ is monotone increasing near $0$. What is there to monotonicity of $f$ near zero aside from saying exactly this?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy: Is the function $f$ increasing just like its approximation.

Comment: @TheoBendit: Is the function $f$ increasing just like its approximation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $f$ is analytic, $f'$ is continuous. And so, since $f'(0)>0$, you have $f'(x)>0$ on some interval $(-\varepsilon,\varepsilon)$ and therefore, yes, $f$ is strictly increasing on that interval.

Comment: Can we find an expression or an approximation of the value of $ε$

Comment: Not without further information.

Comment: @ José Carlos Santos : Can you tel me about these informations, so I can provide them to you.

Comment: @Germany In theory, you could recover a good value for $\varepsilon$ by simply following the argument backwards. By the continuity of $f'$ at $x = 0$, we know that there exists some $\delta > 0$ such that $$|x| < \delta \implies |f'(x) - f'(0)| < f'(0) / 2 \implies f'(x) > f'(0) / 2 > 0.$$ You just need a specific, constructive proof that your $f$ has a continuous derivative at $0$, which will give you the desired $\delta > 0$ based on substituting $\varepsilon = |f'(0)| / 2$. This will totally depend on the function $f$, and how you know it is analytic.